# Best method to update node-webkit content

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I am working on a node-webkit app and am wondering the best way to push updated content to it.

For example say I have files:
index.html 200mbmovie.mp4 image1.jpg image2.jpg.

Now assuming I want to push new content to the node-webkit my initial thought is, send a zipped file over, unzip etc. This most likely isn't the best solution because I dont want to send a 200mbmovie.mp4 over in a zipped package everytime (only if it's been updated).

I am looking for a simple practical solution. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Comment: I have also though about that recently. Will follow this.

Comment: If you only need to update the sources, you could something like nodegit, https://www.npmjs.org/package/nodegit